# iOS8 SDK: Portrait-locked container view controller presenting landscape-locked modal causes severe layout issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios8

When a portrait-locked container view controller presents a landscape-locked view controller modally, the view controllers are subsequently incorrectly laid out until the app is launched, causing serious usability issues.

An example project that displays this issue is also available at https://github.com/eric-horacek/iOS8-Rotation-Presentation-Bug

### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a window
2. Create a container view controller that's locked to portrait orientation
3. Add a child view controller to the custom container view controller using the view controller containment methods
4. Set the container view controller as the root view controller on window
5. Present a view controller modally that's locked to landscape-only orientation

### Expected Results:

The modal view controller is presented in landscape orientation and takes up the entirety of the screen. When dismissed, the orientation returns to portrait.

### Actual Results:

The modal view controller is presented but remains laid out in portrait orientation, clipping the content of the presented view controller. The application status bar correctly rotates to landscape, but the content of the modally-presented view controller remains in portrait orientation, getting clipped off of the bottom of the screen. When the view controller is dismissed, the presenting view controller becomes laid out in landscape orientation, although the device correctly re-orientates back to portrait. This causes the content of the presenting view controller to be clipped as well. This can not be fixed until the app is restarted.

### NOTE:

If the parent view controller is instead a navigation controller (not using custom view controller containment), this works as-intended with no layout issues. However, the issue persists when a custom container view controller is used.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem while using a `UIPageViewController` in the container view controller. Any luck?